# How to recognize/identify different types of objects (textfields, labels, buttons etc) on screen/ from screenshots?

Tags: java, algorithm, image-processing

I would like to make something that is able to recognize different objects on the screen. Lets say I take a screenshot on a window with textfields, labels and buttons. I would like to pass in the image and it should be able to distinguish one from the other. In other words, it should put the name 'textfield' on top of the position where the textfields are located, 'button' on top of buttons and 'label' on top of labels.

Here is a sample image from the internet, to visualize a 'registration window': http://kb.parallels.com/Attachments/12828/Images/registration1.jpg

I would like to do this in Java, but I'm unsure if this is even possible. Does anyone have any ideas where I should start looking? Edge detection? Feature detection? OCR/ICR?

Does this already exist? Anyone ever come across something like this before?

Could someone please point me to the right direction? I would highly appreciate it.

Thank you! :)

Comment: What you seek is not simple. Are you assuming that all objects can be always told apart? There might be cases where a custom editbox could look like a textfield, etc. :::: Anyway, if you are determined to follow this path, then search for the word "segmentation" related to image processing. You should find a lot of info, but not sure that you'll find an off the shelf algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for that info, ilomambo, I know this won't be easy to do, but I'm willing to do my research and come up with something. For now, I'm aiming for the standard windows controls/objects. I'm aiming to make something that is able to 'learn' (using neural networking) and improve itself over time. I just don't really know where to start off from..

I will definitely look into segmentation, thanks!

Comment: Also, the brute force approach, is correlation between a base sample and the target image. :::: The target object might be: shifted, scaled , rotated, or any combination of them. :::: So if you know the complexity of image correlation is O(n^4) JUST FOR ONE PASS, you will conclude yourself how many computation it would take to scale, shift, rotate to all possible scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would work on it:

A) Identification/Segmentation. Without knowing your data, you might be fine with something like "Find a rectangle (or something close to it, since edges are rounded) of less than half of your windows' area" (depends on your data..).

B) Classification. Personally, I'd scale every object you found to size 100*100 (or, whatever) and compare it with sample data (yes, you can scale a mini checkbox to that size. It won't look pretty, but it doesn't matter how it looks like..). Either "brute force" (which is why I scaled) or some nice classification algorithm. (Don't use neural networks, go SVM or nearest neighbour). For classification, I'd mostly look at histograms and shape factors/moments inside the rectangle. If the text confuses the data, get rid of it with some morphology before classification.

Textfields are a bit tricky, but for that, I'd use some OCR library and look at the entire picture. (Personally, I've done well with IMAQ, but it's commercial). If the text is outside a box, you've got yourself a label.

You should probably look into OpenCV.